# Find all roots for the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve $2^x = 4x$. Have taken logs on both sides, represented as an exponent and haven't got it close to the form from which I could find a solution.

Comment: See [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-the-equation-2-x-4x), and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390949/how-do-i-convince-students-in-high-school-for-which-this-equation-2x-4x-have).

Comment: The difference function $x\to 2^x-4x$ is convex, there are two solutions, the one is $4$, the other one is numerically $0.30990693238069053545461578388772986095\dots$ (as delivered by pari/gp via the command `solve( x=0, 3.5, 2^x-4*x )`).

Answer (score 0):

Note you can write $4=2^2$ so that you have $2^x=2^2x$, dividing by $2^2$ you have $2^{x-2}=x$. But this is really as far as this goes since these type of equations require special functions to solve. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%202%5Ex%3D4x) gives 
$$
x= - \dfrac{W_n\left(-\dfrac{\log 2}{4}\right)}{\log 2}
$$
Note that you can try a few 'nice' solutions and see that $x=4$ works.